# How to express Groebner Basis in terms of original elements?

Tags: polynomials, groebner-bases

I have polynomials {A1,B1} and then I find their Groebner basis to be {g1,g2,g3,g4}.

Is there a way for me to express each polynomial g1,g2,g3,g4 in terms of A1, B1? (ie have g1= h1 A1 + h2 B1 where h1,h2 are some polynomial)

I also have the following relation(if it helps), where {k1,k3,j1,j2,j3} are polynomials.

A1 = k1 g1 + k3 g3

B1 = j1 g1 + j2 g2 + j3 g3

Side note: The answer in the similar post was for a different question, and the article linked was too difficult for me to understand and use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Example Request

$A1=-\frac{(M - t)^2 (M + t)^2 (-1 + M t) (1 + M t) (M^2 + t^2)^2 (1 + M^2 t^2)}{M^6 t^6}$

$B1=-\frac{(-1 + M) (1 + M) (1 + M^2) (M - t) (M + t) (-1 + M t) (1 + M t) (M^2 +
    t^2) (1 + M^2 t^2) (-M^4 + t^4 - M^2 t^4 - M^6 t^4 + M^8 t^4 - 
   M^4 t^8)}{M^{10} t^8}$

The solution given by Michael works wonderfully once I get rid of the denominator. (Though I will have to see whether this affects my problem or not.)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/how-to-express-the-original-ideal-elements-in-the-groebner-basis?rq=1)? Also, an explicit example would be helpful here.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes it is a duplicate, but if you read the answer you will see that the original question was not answered. The article that was also linked, I could sadly not understand it. I just want want to express g1,g2,g3,g4 in terms of A1,B1. I am thinking this should be possible since g1,g2,g3,g4 are the groebner basis to A1,B1.

Comment: Umm, what about an example?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for the suggestion, I was not sure if people liked explicit examples or not. I put my problem in the edit.

Comment: We not only like explicit examples, we really need them. In cut-and-pastable form.

Comment: There is now [ExtendedGroebnerBasis](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ExtendedGroebnerBasis/) in the Wolfram Function Repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bas = {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1, x - 2 y^3 - 3};
{gb, mat} = GroebnerBasis`BasisAndConversionMatrix[bas, {x,y,z}, {}]
mat.bas == gb // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Is there a way for this to work if we are working with Laurent Polynomials? What you have put works wonderfully after I multiply out the denominator, but I'm not sure if it will affect my problem. Thank You so much for you help!

Comment: @AndyNguyen I'm not sure. A copy-pastable example (code, not TeX), would make it easier to try out ideas.  It seems like the monomial ordering of $1/t^{-1}, 1/t^{-2}$ is the opposite of $t,1$ in $(t+1)/t^2$ (for the purposes of a Gröbner basis).

Comment: It did affect our problem, but my professor found a way to circumvent it and still be able to use the solution you have provided. Thank you so much for helping.